# External Credential - Unable to use on Digital Experience

Tags: apex, namedcredentials, digital-experience

I have created a new Named Credential with External Credential (named `B2BL_Mulesoft_Integrations`) and mapped it to the correct permission sets using the **Identity Type** as **Named Principal**.

Can you please help me with what I am missing?

**Update 14-Dec-2022**: I have opened case# 43776623.

When I attempt to use Apex Class in Digital Experience under a Checkout Flow, it throws the exception as seen below:

```
15:37:59.78 (78218899)|NAMED_CREDENTIAL_RESPONSE|NamedCallout[Named Credential Id=null, Named Credential Name=null, Status Code=0, Content-Type=null, Response Size bytes=0, Overall Callout Time ms=0, Connect Time ms=0
15:37:59.10 (78972740)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[11]|System.CalloutException: We couldn't access the credential(s). You might not have the required permissions, or the external credential "B2BL_Mulesoft_Integrations" might not exist.
```

It works well with System Administrator but not with the Digital Experience user assigned the permission set. I have granted access to Read+Create+Edit+Delete to the permission set **User External Credentials**.

Note: I have also attemted to change the code from `with sharing` to `without sharing` with no success.

The code is the usual:

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('callout:B2BL_Stock_Check');
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
req.setBody('...');
Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
```

External Authentication config:
[image]

Named Credential config:
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I can see, Named Credential mapping does not work with **Permission Set Groups**.

The workaround was the assign the permission set directly to the user.

I have found this [Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Les3kUAB/allow-named-credentials-to-be-mapped-using-permission-set-group). I hope this was documented. It could have saved us one day. It would be even better if Permission Set Groups worked as designed.

**TL;DR**: as of 15-Dec-22, Named Credentials mapping works only with permission sets assigned directly to the user.

Comment: I have all in place but still seems like I am missing something, even if use my sys admin profile or I assign the perm set directly to my user, when I  execute the apex callout I get the same exception "We couldn't access the credential(s). You might not have the required permissions, or the external credential "......." might not exist." any ideas?

Comment: This resolved it for me...and also agreed with you. We lost a whole day of testing on this lol.

Answer (score 3):

This question gave me a hint, and my problem was solved by granting Read permission to the **User External Credentials** object via a permission set. Not sure why this isn't documented, but it solved my problem.

Note that I'm also using a flow to kick off the callout via Apex action.

Comment: I'm having trouble navigating the documentation on External Credentials, too :) I believe it's documented here: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.nc_user_external_credentials.htm&type=5

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer saved my day.